# increment the cell in excel: error attempt to overwrite cell

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, xlwt

I am new in excel-python. I wanted to export values in to excel from python. I have simple code as below.

```
import xlwt
book = xlwt.Workbook (encoding = "utf-8")
sheet1 = book.add_sheet ("sheet 1")
sheet1.write(0,0,"Display")
x = 1
m = 1
for x in range (1,9):
    sheet1.write (m,0,x)
    print (x)
    x = x+1
for m in range (1,9):
    m = m +1 
    book.save("trial.xls")
```

after running this code i am getting errors like:

> Exception: attempt to overwrite cell: sheetname= u'sheet 1' rowx=9
>   colx = 0 and print (x) is printing the values of x till 2.

Can some one correct me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: problem got solved by using xlsxwriter module. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the second for loop, because the first one will loop it until the range of 9 ends. I'm right?

```
for x in range (1,9):
    sheet1.write (m,0,x)
    print (x)
    x = x+1
    m = m +1
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create a sheet, you need to explicitly allow overwriting (it's disabled by default) as below:

```
sheet1 = book.add_sheet ("sheet 1",cell_overwrite_ok=True)
```